# Visual studio throws System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A5023' on using Crystal report

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports, visual-studio-2019

I think this is new error Because i cant find anything with System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A5023' key word in google

**My Code**

```
   Public Sub tampilkantiket()
    AxCrystalReport1.SelectionFormula = "totex{{pemesanan.id_pemesanan}}='" & txtidpemesanan.Text & "'"
    AxCrystalReport1.ReportFileName = "Tiket.rpt"
    AxCrystalReport1.WindowState = Crystal.WindowStateConstants.crptMaximized
    AxCrystalReport1.RetrieveDataFiles()
    AxCrystalReport1.Action = 1
   End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are two possible solutions you can try that will work.

1. Check the tables / fields you want to reference. The contents of
   `AxCrystalReport1.SelectionFormula` may be wrong. You need to ensure that they are correct.
2. Check the version and the controls you use to generate the report in your application. A report created by crystal ver higher
       than 8    should be generated by a control that corresponds to that
       version or    higher, if you can avoid ActiveXs get in .net
       controls.